# Download and automatically rename to the hyperlink text all PDF files on a page

Tags: download, batch-rename

I use Chrono Download Manager for bulk downloading all files of X type on a given page and it works very well.

I am interested in downloading many PDF files from a website, all of which have non-descriptive filenames. The hyperlinked text for each file, however, is perfectly descriptive.

Is there any reasonable way for a non-coder to pull off downloading all of those files and automatically renaming each one so the filename is the same as the hyperlinked text for the download?

If it makes a difference, [this](https://www.csb.gov/records-details/?F_All=y&Type=1) is the page.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how that would help, as my only obstacle is automatically renaming auto-downloaded files in accordance with their hyperlink text. Am I missing something about aria2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following procedure with [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) is not full automatic. You have to manually copy and paste all the download links in a simple text file. but [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) can automatically download and rename according to that text file.

So how do you make that text file? First create a new text file in any text editor. Let that text file name `aria2-script.txt` or any name you want. Put the dircet download links in it. Remember to put the **direct download links only** otherwise aria2 download the webpage. Here is the syntax of that `aria2-script.txt` file:

```
http://example-link.com/direct-link/fileA.pdf
  out=fileA.pdf
  checksum=sha-1=sha-goes-here
```

You may skip the checksum part. Add many links as you want. Remember to put **TWO spaces** before `out=` and `checksum=` (and other options) otherwise aria2 will take it as an URL. For example, your text file will be:

```
https://www.csb.gov/assets/Record/Board_Action_Report_-_Notation_Item_2018-57.pdf
  out=Recommendation 2012-03-I-CA-R14, from the Chevron Refinery Fire investigation.pdf

https://www.csb.gov/assets/Record/Board_Action_Report_-_Notation_Item_2018-56.pdf
  out=Recommendation 2012-03-I-CA-R13, from the Chevron Refinery Fire investigation.pdf
```

Copy those direct download links by right clicking on the file link in that webpage. Now download aria2 from it's [GitHub release page](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/releases), open command prompt in that folder and run the command:

```
aria2c.exe --check-certificate=false --dir="Folder" --input-file="aria2-script.txt"
```

The `--check-certificate=false` option is to just remove certification complexity. There are many options to speed up the download procedure. aria2 will automatically rename those files. Remember to put full path of `aria2c.exe` and `aria2-script.txt` file. For further details read this [aria2 options list](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#options) and [aria2 input file](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#id2).

Comment: I think it only will not work because, as can be seen in the example, the download links are not direct.

Answer (score 0):

Really old question i know , but i came upon this while searching so it has pretty good google indexing so I'm leaving solution for the future generations. This method even works when the files are behind some kind of authorization as it acts on behalf of user. I used this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-mass-downloader/abdkkegmcbiomijcbdaodaflgehfffed
I selected link , right click , add to the list, select "multi-rename" .  Perform batch replacement as instructed below.
In the box search for type "{auto}"
In the box replace type "{link}.{ext}"
This will make all files names in the following schema
"The hyperlink text" is the name and extension as provided.